# SSH Connection Blocked to my NAS but not sure why

Tags: networking, router, ssh, openssh, nmap

I typically connect to a NAS from another PC via SSH, but recently the connection has stopped working and I'm not sure what's causing the issue.  Typically, I connect over a dynamic IP hosting site, which points to my router's IP, although trying to SSH locally over the network is also failing.  The router, shared between the NAS and the external PC, forwards a port to the NAS to enable me to use SSH even when I am not on the local network.  The NAS runs an openSSH server to host the sessions.  I'm not sure if the issue is my router, NAS, or both.  Here is what I checked

External PC:

- Pinging online domain -- Address unreachable
- Pinging Router IP -- Works
- Pinging NAS IP (local network) -- Destination Host Unreachable
- SSH over online domain -- No route to host
- SSH by Router IP -- Connection Refused
- SSH by NAS IP -- No route to host
- SSH by NAS hostname -- Name or Service Unknown (a prior problem)

From NAS:

- Pinging online domain -- Address unreachable
- Pinging Router IP -- Works
- Pinging NAS IP (local network) -- Destination Host Unreachable
- SSH over online domain -- No route to host
- SSH by Router IP -- Connection Refused
- SSH by NAS IP -- No route to host
- SSH by NAS hostname -- Connection Established

SSH is running on the NAS (checked via service status of sshd process).  Netstat shows that sshd is running at a local address of **0.0.0.0:portnum**.  I have tried restarting the server and the NAS, but it hasn't worked.

- Nmap for online domain -- can find the forwarded SSH port, but says the port is filtered
- Nmap for router IP -- cannot find the forwarded SSH port
- Nmap for NAS IP -- "Host Seems Down"
- Nmap for NAS by hostname -- finds forwarded SSH port, in an open state.

To add onto the strangeness, even though the pings seem to fail when directed to the online domain, entering the domain in my browser brings me to my router's logon page, as does the router's IP.

I checked router settings and it appears it still is applying the port-forwarding rule I had.  I can connect to the internet with it for normal operation just fine.  It is a Linksys N600 Wi-Fi Router E2500.

I use dynu to provide dynamic DNS.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Check the client and server SSH logs _(server verbosity will likely need to be changed to `DEBUG3`)_ after trying to connect - if no connection attempt is registered in the server log with `DEBUG3` set, work backwards, checking the firewall on the forwarding PC, and the firewall log and rules on the router. _(**General FYI:** router login pages should **never** be WAN accessible - if requiring access to the router's WebUI via WAN, connect to the router via SSH and forward a port through the SSH tunnel or connect to the router via the router's VPN and access it over the VPN tunnel.)_

Comment: Sounds to me that the private/LAN IP of the NAS has changed due to DHCP (Have you forgot to do DHCP reservation for it or maybe something happened to its MAC address or hostname?)

Comment: Thanks Tom, it turns out that the local IP for the NAS had changed, so the router was forwarding the messages to a device that didn't exist.  I guess I'll have to make that DHCP reservation to avoid a repeat incident.